# \mathrm{\Delta} in slant in the equation environment

Tags: equations, templates, slanted

I tried to write an equation, including \Delta. But it also shows in slant, even though I tried \mathrm{} or \text{}.
CUEDthesisPSnPDF template and two math packages are used

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
  \Delta E \Delta{t} \approx \frac{h}{2 \pi}\\
  \mathrm{\Delta} E \, \text{\Delta} t
  \label{fun:naturalline}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

It seems \mathrm does not work here.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can have a look at package `upgreek`.

Comment: What would make the Delta less slanted? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_(letter)

Comment: Where did you obtain `CUEDthesisPSnPDF`?  I'm almost certain that the class file sets the greek symbols to italic, but we can't say without *all* information.

Comment: I did an online search for the template and chose the first result https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template.  Then I cannot reproduce: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZREZ.png).  Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke thank you! I just got it from someone...I compared both of the templates and they do have a lot differences. Since upgreek package works, I will just leave the differences aside and it saves works.

Comment: The LaTeX kernel sets things up in such a way that `\Delta` yields an upright (uppercase) delta; the `amsmath` package offers, in addition, `\varDelta` for an italic (slanted) uppercase delta (and similarly for other uppercase greek letters).  See [@HenriMenke’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473003/mathrm-delta-in-slant-in-the-equation-environment#comment1192574_473003).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load the [upgreek](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/upgreek) package and write `\Updelta` to generate an 'upright' uppercase-Delta character.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
$\delta$ $\updelta$

$\Delta$ $\Updelta$ % note: \Updelta, not \upDelta
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;dr:** Several packages define `\increment` or `\upDelta`.

If you can use `unicode-math`, there are a number of different variants of this symbol, and a number of different ways to get it:

```
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames, Svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[math-style=literal]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
% Make it blatant which font is being used:
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale = 1.0, Color = Crimson]
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Color = DarkGray]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Color = Orange]
\setmathfont[range=up]{Latin Modern Math}[Color = SkyBlue]
\setmathfont[range=bfsfup]{Latin Modern Sans}[Color = Indigo]
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}[Color = LimeGreen]

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}increment} \( \increment \)
  \item \texttt{Δ} \(Δ\)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}upDelta} \( \upDelta \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}mupDelta} \( \mupDelta \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}symup\{\textbackslash{}Delta\}} \( \symup{\Delta} \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}mathrm\{\textbackslash{}mupDelta\}} \( \mathrm{\mupDelta} \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}mathup\{\textbackslash{}mupDelta\}} \( \mathup{\mupDelta} \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}mbox\{\textbackslash{}mupDelta\}} \( \mbox{\mupDelta} \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}mbox\{Δ\}} \( \mbox{Δ} \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}mbfsansDelta} \( \mbfsansDelta \)
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash{}symbfsfup\{\textbackslash{}Delta\}} \( \symbfsfup{\Delta} \)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Delta samples]

And at least three more, but you get the idea.  Of these, `\increment` is the math operator ∆ (U+2206) and the others are the Greek letter Δ (U+0394).

If you need backward compatibility with PDFTeX, one way to get it is to load an upright Greek alphabet with `isomath`.  Another is to load an upright font with Greek letters as a math alphabet (such as AMS Euler, `zeur`) and define either `\increment` or `\upDelta` with `\DeclareMathSymbol`.

Several legacy packages define this symbol in different ways, including:

- `upgreek`: `\upDelta`
- `stix`, `stix2`: `\increment`
- `kpfonts`: `\Deltaup`
- `fourier`: `\otherDelta`